# PHP convert special characters to HTML entity

Tags: php, wordpress, unicode

I have a string ex:

$a = 'abcabc';

The 'small blue diamond' is: `bin2hex('') => f09f94b9`

[Small blue diamond representation](https://codepoints.net/U+1F539)

So, I would like to convert the $a string into a string which represents the small blue diamond with the HTML-escape: `&#x1f539;`

What would be the function what I should call to convert all unicode character into the HTML-escape representation?

### More details on this case

In WordPress when I want to insert the $a variable into a table, $wpdb does it checks. [Link to WPDB source code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/wp-db.php)

When WordPress prepares the `$data` which should be inserted or updated, it runs the fields on the `$wpdb->strip_invalid_text` method and then it check if anything invalid found in the `$data`. It the text in the $a variable invalid with the following regexp:

```
                $regex = '/
                (
                    (?: [\x00-\x7F]                  # single-byte sequences   0xxxxxxx
                    |   [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]       # double-byte sequences   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
                    |   \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]   # triple-byte sequences   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx * 2
                    |   [\xE1-\xEC][\x80-\xBF]{2}
                    |   \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]
                    |   [\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}';
            if ( 'utf8mb4' === $charset ) {
                $regex .= '
                    |    \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2} # four-byte sequences   11110xxx 10xxxxxx * 3
                    |    [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}
                    |    \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}
                ';
            }
            $regex .= '){1,40}                          # ...one or more times
                )
                | .                                  # anything else
                /x';
            $value['value'] = preg_replace( $regex, '$1', $value['value'] );
            if ( false !== $length && mb_strlen( $value['value'], 'UTF-8' ) > $length ) {
                $value['value'] = mb_substr( $value['value'], 0, $length, 'UTF-8' );
            }
```

When the 'small blue diamond' represented with `f09f94b9`, this regexp marks the data invalid. When it is represented with `&#x1f539;`. So what I need is to convert that unicode characters into a representation what is accepted by WordPress.

Comment: This is not possible. There are roughly 112.000 UTF-8 characters defined currently, but only very few HTML escape sequences. HTML escaping is not the tool you are looking for. Instead you want to take care that all of your tool chain uses UTF-8 encoding so that such characters are not special any more. Since there actually is no such thing as "special characters". There are only many, many different characters.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks, I have updated the question with details why would I need such function. Maybe you can suggest me a solution :)

Comment: As said before: the unicode sequence is perfectly fine and valid. The issue is not that sequence. The issue is that apparently at least parts of your tool chain are _not_ using unicode internally. _That_ is what you want to change. _Solve the cause of an issue, not the symptom_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I came up with to convert all of the characters you can modify it further to only convert characters in the range you need.

```
$s = 'abcdef';
$a = preg_split('//u', $s, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach($a as $c){
    echo '&#' . unpack('V', iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4LE', $c))[1] . ';';
}
```

Comment: In WordPress, we had to change the field to utf8mb4 collation and that did the trick without converting the input. BTW your solution is great, I have even added a little improvement :)